Как активировать связь меж таблиц в power bi?
В ходе погружения в power bi столкнулась с такой проблемой: не могу активировать связь меж таблиц. Есть 2 таблицы главные: (ИМ)Детализация и (ПОС)Голая выгрузка. Я создала таблицу "Направления" с данными из "(ИМ)Детализация"[Группа тем] и "(ПОС)Голая выгрузка"[Категории]. И также создала таблицу "Категории" из "(ИМ)Детализация"[Тема] и "(ПОС)Голая выгрузка"[Подкатегория]. Создала связи:

Далее создала матрицы, левая с направлениями, правая с категориями.

Они должны быть связаны поскольку есть необходимость тыкать на какое либо направление и видеть в правой матрице категории выбранного направления. Но! Сама проблема в том, что направления и категории я собирала по двум таблицам и соединяла в общие данные все. Отсюда если я выбираю направление с таблицы "(ИМ)Детализация", то вижу кол-во категорий этого направления в правой матрице, а если выбираю направление с таблицы "(ПОС)Голая выгрузка", то не вижу уже кол-во категорий этого направления в матрице. Уже поняла, что загвоздка в неактивной связи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и как решили вопрос? Прошарила весь интернет в доль и поперек, решение так и не нашла(
